# How to access public members in private method in R6Class?

Tags: r, private-methods, r6, public-members

```
library(R6)

Person<-R6Class("Person",
    public=list(
      name=NULL,
      age=NULL,
      initialize=function(name,age){
        self$name<-name
        self$age<-age
      },
      GrowUP1=function(){
        self$publicGrow()
      },
      publicGrow=function(){
        self$age<-self$age+1
      },
      GrowUP2=function(){
        self$privateGrow()
      }
    ),
    private=list(
      privateGrow=function(){
        self$age<-self$age+1
      }
    )
)

Person<-Person$new('Tom',20)
Person$age
Person$GrowUP1()
Person$age
Person$GrowUP2()
```

This is my sample code.
I run last code `Person$GrowUP2()`.
But, I got error `Error in Person$GrowUP2() : attempt to apply non-function`

I do not know why this code is not running.I want to use private method in order to modify public member.How to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the private functions using `private`:

```
GrowUP2=function(){
        private$privateGrow()
        }

Person<-Person$new('Tom',20)
Person$GrowUP1()
Person$GrowUP2() 
Person$age

[1] 22
```